# Creating a path for a jersey resource

Tags: rest, jersey

If I want to get projects for userid= 1
then my url looks like

```
https://localhost:8080/proj_name/api/user/1/projects
```

How should I construct my resource path if I want to get projects not associated with a particular user id?
Any suggestions?
Should it be like this or something else?

```
https://localhost:8080/proj_name/api/projects?excludeUserId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ne operator of rql (resource query language).

Comment: is there a java implementation of rql?

Comment: There’s an rql parser for java https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser but I have never personally used it before.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and referred this post [How can I pass complex objects as arguments to a RESTful service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061292/how-can-i-pass-complex-objects-as-arguments-to-a-restful-service)

I used option 2 from the answer posted on the above stackoverflow post and ended up having urls like

```
https://localhost:8080/proj_name/api/projects
https://localhost:8080/proj_name/api/projects?filter={"equalUserId":"1"}
https://localhost:8080/proj_name/api/projects?filter={"notEqualUserId":"1"}
```